# Disable back press in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, onbackpressed

I have an activity **Main Activity** which has two fragments **ListFragment** and **DetailFragment** . While i'm on __Detail Fragment i don't want the back press to be pressed twice.

> Main Activity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!isViewClicked) {
        isViewClicked = true;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Here i'm simply trying to block the pressing of back button twice.
But this doesn't seem to work.
Here by blocking i mean, Once pressed, Come from Details to List. If pressed one more app gets minimized, which i don't want to occur.

Comment: What do you mean by *block pressing back button twice* ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Manoj Where do you want to go if you press back button on Detail fragment?

Comment: @tahsinRupam i added description

Comment: @manoj IF I understood correctly, Do you want to close the app when you press back button on Details fragment?

Comment: Once pressed, Come from Details to List. If pressed one more app gets minimized, which i don't want to occur.

Comment: @tahsinRupam I just added a log in bakpressed, even if i press back press twice quickly, it shows only once.

Comment: can you post the code that you used for fragment transaction?

Comment: @ManojFrekzz You may try out my answer below. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think your issue is that you're adding fragment each time instead of replacing one fragment with another.

Comment: @ManojFrekzz - Can you try my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of `DetailFragment` in your `Activity` you can use `isAdded()` method of the fragment to check if it is currently added in your `Activity`

In order to find the instance of the fragment, you can use

`getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);`
  **or**
`getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(ID);`

Comment: i checked the fragment is null or not. Still the problem persists

Comment: if it is not null check, if it is added to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting you exactly but I am giving you trick which i used in my project. I edit it in your code. I don't know what is **isViewClicked**. But
Please check if it is useful to you.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        int count = this.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count != 0)
        {
            //Do your stuff
        }else if (!isViewClicked) {
            isViewClicked = true;
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Manoj Frekzz, Have you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this to your activity which contains your `ListFragment` and `DetailedFragment`. Remove `onBackPressed()` from `ListFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried to understand your question. From what I understood is

You have Activity A - List Fragment > Detail Fragment.

When you press back button on Detail Fragment you come back to List Fragment, It's what you need.
But press back button again from List Fragment should NOT close/exit your app.

So here is what you need to do.

Add List Fragment to **MainActivity** like this:

```
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    Fragment listFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Listfragment here
        listFragment = new ListFragment();
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, listFragment, "List");
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("List");
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();    }
```

And same way in List Fragment call Detail Fragment like:

```
mListview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
                mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, detailFragment, "Detail");
                mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Detail");
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

In You **MainActivity**

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(listFragment.isVisible()){
            **//Do Nothing - DOES NOT CLOSE THE APP**
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE** :

**Please don't do this unless you have a good reason, as breaking the expected model of operation very slightly hurts the entire platform**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to minimize your app you should write below code in your `MainActivity` or `ListFragement` but I suggested `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }
```